# Facebook email blocked due to privacy settings

Tags: facebook, email

I sent an email to someones Facebook using my Gmail address. It came back stating I was blocked by his privacy settings.  Is this because I do not use Facebook, therefore, I am not his friend so it automatically blocks me?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's email service does have two privacy options, one being **Basic Filtering** and the other being **Strict Filtering**. Your friend may have the strict filtering on, which may be causing issues. Under the privacy tab, the options for this look like the below:

[image: filtering options]